# Prove $x^{\frac{p}{q}}$ is well-defined when $x < 0$ and $q$ is odd.

Tags: real-analysis

My Algebra 2 teacher stated that $x^{\frac{p}{q}}$ is not defined in the real number system for $x < 0$, even if $q$ is odd. However, in every real analysis textbook I've read, discrete real exponentiation is allowed for $x < 0$ so long as $q$ is odd. My teacher presented the following proof:

$$(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}} = \sqrt[3]{-8} = -2$$
$$(-8)^{\frac{2}{6}} = (\sqrt[6]{-8})^2 = \text{undefined}$$
$$(-8)^{\frac{2}{6}} = (\sqrt[6]{-8^2}) = \sqrt[6]{64} = 2$$
$$8^{\frac{1}{3}} \neq 8^{\frac{2}{6}}$$

I don't see what this proves, however. All this shows is $8^{\frac{1}{3}} \neq 8^{\frac{2}{6}}$, which is true in the real number system, but it doesn't show that $8^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is undefined.

Is there a way to prove $x^{\frac{p}{q}}$ is well defined for $x < 0$ as long as $q$ is odd, or is it simply just by the definition of a textbook?

Comment: First, your teacher proved that $(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}} \neq (-8)^{\frac{2}{6}}$ instead of $8^{\frac{1}{3}} \neq 8^{\frac{2}{6}}$. And if you a have just one example telling you why $x^{\frac{p}{q}}$ doesn't work when $x<0$, then $x^{\frac{p}{q}}$ is not well defined. Well defined means that we can't have any ambiguity, and with this example, we have at least one.

Comment: Mathematics work in this way: if you want to show that a statement wokrs for all $x$, then you think how to prove it in a general way. And if you want to show that something doesn't work you just give an example (or counterexample). The second way is the way that your teacher take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact what is proven by your teacher is that when $p$ and $q$ are not coprimes, then $\left(x^p\right)^\frac 1 q$ can be different from $\left(x^\frac 1 q\right)^p$ and $x^\left(\frac p q\right)$ can also be different.

But as soon as you write $x^\frac 2 6$ you are using the 2 variables function $x^y$ where $x$ is here an arbitrary real number and $y$ is the rational number $\frac 2 6 = \frac 1 3$.

So even if I can understand the reason for this demonstration, because students have to be warned of corner cases, my personal opinion is that writing $x^\frac 1 3 \neq x^\frac 2 6$ is not mathematicaly rigourous.

The actual problem is that $a^b$ can have slightly different definitions depending on the definition domains:

- $a\in\mathbb R$ and $b\in\mathbb N^*$: no problem it is the usage that we learn in college classes
- $a\in\mathbb R^*$ and $b\in \mathbb Z$: close to previous using $a^{-b} = \frac 1 {a^b}$ provided $a \neq 0$
- $a\in\mathbb R_+^*$ and $b\in\mathbb R$: $a^b = e^{b \times ln(a)}$! This is the true reason why mathematicians are reluctant to use non integer powers on negative real numbers.

While being slightly different, all of the above definitions are consistent with the well known $\left(a^b\right)^c = a^\left(b\times c\right)$ property

Trying to generalise $a\in\mathbb R^*$ and $b\in\mathbb Q$ would lead to nightmares because that property is no longer true.

The usage for $a\in\mathbb R_+$, $p\in\mathbb N$ or for $a\in\mathbb R, q\in \mathbb N, p=2q+1$ to write $a^\frac 1 p =\sqrt[p]a$ is common and harmless, *provided the user is aware that $\left(a^b\right)^c = a^\left(b\times c\right)$ may no longer be used in the general case*.

---

For the post to be complete, I must add the complex field:

- $a\in\mathbb Z^*$ and $b\in\mathbb Z$ then $a^b = e^{b \times ln(a)}$

Here everything is again clearly defined but as the exponential function is $2i\pi$ periodic, we must be aware that $\left(a^b\right)^c = a^\left(b\times c\right)$ can only be used with caution...

Comment: So, it's simply just ambiguous and decided by the axiom a textbook follows?